# Preventing downloading a lot of your public S3 files?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there any kind of protection for hosting files (images) in S3 and preventing that someone download zillion times a file just to damage you (AWS billing)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services such as twitpic do this by:

- Removing public/anonymous access to the files
- Signing an access request with a short expiry time. (eg 30 seconds or so).
- Providing the signed url to the end user.

This means that someone can access the file, but they have to retrieve it before the request expiry time.

Of course, it is then up to you to not sign requests from people who are abusing your site.